# html dangerous tags to avoid while developing a chat application

Tags: html, tags

I am developing a chat application using PHP and jQuery... all messages sent by the chat pair are appended to a `<div>`. While doing this, I found that tags such as `<script>` can be entered by users. What tags should I avoid while appending the user's message?

Comment: `<Script>` `<iframe>` I think.

Comment: I [just made an HTML sanitizer](https://github.com/minitech/blog/blob/php/system/utilities.php#L76), actually. It uses [a whitelist](https://github.com/minitech/blog/blob/php/config/config.json#L16). I think those are sensible defaults.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Link is dead :/

Comment: @user3284463: Ah, shoot, I forgot there was actually content in that repo. Looking for it, hold on…

Comment: @Ryan Still dead 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never use any black-list approach (which basically bans bad items), because there is always a chance that you either forget something, or that hackers will find a way to bypass your blacklist (eg. by using unicode). Instead, try using white-list approach, that is, create a set of acceptable tags and ban everything else.

Comment: can you suggest some tags that i can white-list.like  `<img>`

Comment: Well, definitely do not add anything to the white list that people classified as "bad" in these answers, but me, personally, I can't be certain about which tags can be hacked or abused. Marquee might not be dangerous, but can be VERY annoying. Often people don't even use HTML tags, but create their own (like Stack Overflow itself - *, **, etc.)

Comment: Not to mention acceptable attributes — `onmouseover`, anyone? Also `<a href="javascript:` and `<img src="javascript:` (on really old browsers, that last one). Also `<!--` messages followed by `-->` (or vice-versa) that blank out whole sections of a page. `style` attributes are probably not good to allow, either. And don’t put in anything form-related, of course.

Comment: ...or css that allows insertion of small amounts of javascript! You can use something like [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison). That page clearly states what the problem is with a lot of other options.

Answer (score 10):

Avoid tags that will inject content into the page:

- applet
- script
- style
- link
- iframe

Other tags may be necessary to remove, as well. Maybe you don't want to embed images. These are things that you will need to determine. At the bare minimum, allow `<p>` and `<br />`.

Comment: [W3C](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/SecurityRisk.html) lists the next tags as "potentially dangerous": `comment`, `embed`, `link`, `listing`, `meta`, `noscript`, `object`, `plaintext`, `script`, `xmp`.